# Solution to Execute a query using ajax when browser is closed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to update my database when a user close the browser. I am using ajax and   window.onbeforeunload . Here is the code. Code does not execute. Suggest me where i am going wrong

**First.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'logout.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    timeout: 4000
});
};
</script>
```

**logout.php**

```
    <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


$selected = mysql_select_db("examples",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

$result =  mysql_query("DELETE FROM cars WHERE id='1'");
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This:** the above code should create a file *logger.txt* and write to it when you close the window.

**First.php:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'logout.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        timeout: 4000
    });
})
</script>
```

**logout.php**  //you can add your code here

```
$filename = "logger.txt";
$fd = fopen($filename, "a");
$dump="it came here";

$str = sprintf("[%s] %s", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $dump);

fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
fclose($fd);
```

Comment: There is a bit problem. I want to execute query whenever the browser or tab is closed, but if there exists any button or link in that page and i click on any of them then the query also execute. . Can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below and check if it works!

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'logout.php',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                timeout: 4000
            });
        });
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't get any result

Comment: It seems unload & onbeforeunload are the two options available. But these commands are not reliable & NOT recommended.

Looking at some older questions, below is what they have to say:-


If you definitely need this, Send a request every minute basically telling the server "I'm still here". Then, if the server doesn't receive such a request for more than two minutes (you have to take into account latencies etc.), you consider the client offline.